# How to test homogeneity of variance if the data may not be normally distributed?

Tags: time-series, distributions, normal-distribution

I need a test to check for homogeneity of variances. I am not sure if a series is normally distributed.

- If I use a test of homogeneity of variance that works for NON-normally distributed data, does the series also pass (with "pass" I mean that the variances ARE homogeneous) if the distribution is normal ?
- Can we say that a test of "non-normal" is more tolerant than a "normal" test?
  (obviously I'm always referring to the distribution of the data)

I know there are tests to check if the distribution is normal or not, but I would like to take away this doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew F-test can be used for test of equality of variances. However, I just read from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test) that it is very sensitive to non-normal data. However, there are other alternative tests mentioned there such as: [Levene's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test), [Bartlett's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) and [Brown-Forsythe test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%E2%80%93Forsythe_test). Maybe this is of use to you?

Comment: yes, but maybe after the change of the text from the moderator the question is not very clear. I mean, can a test used from non-normal distribution also good for a normal distribution? I know what are the tests, I also know the tests you wrote, but my main question is to understand with a non-normal test applied to a normal distribution can do the job correctly

Comment: If I generalize your question a bit more, you are asking what's the difference between parametric and non-parametric tests and can a non-parametric test be used for samples that follow a _known distribution_? The answer is _yes_, but non-parametric tests suffer from [low power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-parametric_test#Applications_and_purpose).